# I have added google calendar event with use of content Value from android programatically

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have an issue is event added in google calendar but event add after 1 month from selected date means I have added an event for 15th May 2019. but event set on 15th June 2019 in google calendar. I have added below code for event set.

```
 long startMillis = 0;
            long endMillis = 0;
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(2019, 05, 15, 6, 00);
            startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2019, 05, 15, 8, 00);
            endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

            ContentValues contentEvent = new ContentValues();
            contentEvent.put("calendar_id", mCalendarID);
            contentEvent.put("title", "Wedding");
            contentEvent.put("description", "Wedding Party");
            contentEvent.put("eventLocation", "New York");
            contentEvent.put("dtstart", startMillis);
            contentEvent.put("dtend", endMillis);
            contentEvent.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            contentEvent.put("allDay", 1);
            contentEvent.put("hasAlarm",1);
            Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
            getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, contentEvent);
            cursor.close();
```

Please let me know the solution to my issue. It will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

'beginTime.set(2019, 05, 15, 6, 00);'

Means: 2019 July 15 06:00

I think what you want is 'beginTime.set(2019, **04**, 15, 6, 00);'

The second value start from 0, and JANUARY is 0.

This wrote in Calendar.java

```
Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the
month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of
the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is
<code>JANUARY</code> which is 0; the last depends on the number
of months in a year.
```

Comment: So how can i add calendar like start from 1 = January.

Comment: Thanks man but  how can i do to set actual date event with starting from 1 to 12 not 0 to 11.

Comment: You can try joda time. This lib offer an easy way to set/get time. [Here](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is the site. It is like val time = DateTime.now().withYear(2019).withMonthOfYear(5).withDayOfMonth(15), set to 2019-4-15 , and get the next month by time.plusMonth(1).

Comment: And for the android, you can put this into your gradle: implement 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'.

Comment: Thanks But not possible to change time because of i am using calendar and it's default Calendar class.

Comment: OK, maybe you can define field like private static final int JAN = 0; FEB = 1; And then try beginTime.set(2019, MAY, 15, 6, 00);